# Replacement involving unique characters

Tags: replacement

I want to do a replacements such that: `f[P1,P2,P3]` goes to  `P1[a]P2[b]P3[c] g[a,b,c]` where I want the `a`,`b`,`c` to be unique.

More general, I want products like `f[P1,P2,P3] f[Q1,Q2,Q3]` to go to `P1[a1]P2[b1]P3[c1] g[a1,b1,c1] Q1[a2]Q2[b2]Q3[c2] g[a2,b2,c2]` where again `a1`,`a2`,`b1`,`b2`,`c1`,`c2` are guaranteed to be unique non conflicting characters.

Comment: This looks awfully like an XY problem. What are you *actually* trying to do here?

Comment: @J.M. Sure I will update the question in a minute and include X ([XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)), but does that mean that there is no very simple solution to this question itself? (Since you seem to think the underlying problem is easier to solve in a different way.). I would think that this is a very fundamental operation that would have way more applications than the specific problem I am trying to solve right now.

Comment: Local replacement can be done through `ReplacePart[]`, but this seems like a very unwieldy way of doing what you want here.

Comment: @Carl, great, hadn't found that one. I agree that is the same question. This should be marked a duplicate (can't do that myself right?).

Comment: Or you can change your question to what you actually want to do. Something like `f[P1, P2, P3] /. f[a__] :> With[{v = Table[Unique[], Length[{a}]]}, Inner[Compose, {a}, v, Times] g @@ v]` would work.

Comment: Maybe it would be possible to solve your problem using [build-in tensor algebra functions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Tensors.html).

Comment: We can reopen if you can refocus your question as Carl suggested.

Comment: @Carl, thanks you very much. You gave me both the practical answer and led me to the one that let me satisfy my curiosity. I will change the question to focus on the real problem so that your comment is the appropriate answer. I should have kept looking for the right replacement rule a bit longer. You have great skills that you saw the solution instantly (but I guess you have quite some experience with Mathematica, seeing how the documentation says Compose was superseded by Composition in 1991).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following replacement rule to achieve what you want:

```
f[P1, P2, P3] /. f[a__] :> With[{v=Table[Unique[],Length[{a}]]},
    Inner[Compose, {a}, v, Times] g@@v
]
```

> g[\$9, \$10, \$11] P1[\$9] P2[\$10] P3[\$11]

Note that [`Compose`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Compose) is a deprecated function that still works, and I like it. You can replace [`Compose`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Compose) with `#1[#2]&` if you prefer to use non-deprecated functions.

Also, as @KJ says, you could consider using the built-in tensor algebra functions. For example, you could represent your output as:

```
TensorContract[
    TensorProduct[P1, P2, P3, g],
    {{1,4}, {2,5}, {3,6}}
]
```

This representations avoids the need to create dummy indices.